# How to use event weights in TMVA ROOT

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to train and perform classifiers from TMVA. My data set contains event weights besides event data.

In the *TMVA::Factory* there's a method *setWeightExpression* to specify event weights. What are the event weights good for? Why it doesn't exist similar possibility to set event weights in *TMVA::Reader*?

Regards,
Vladimir